# FTP download directory c++

Tags: .net, visual-c++

How can i download all directory from server recursively. I use WinINet and this problem solve very hard. I interested there is some easy way that download files and folders from ftp on visual-c++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to use FTP mget command. Otherwise, if possible you can zip the whole directory on the server and use FTP get. Else, you can use rsync, which provides the additional functionality of syncing any change you make later on within the directory on the server.

See [this discussion](http://forums.macosxhints.com/archive/index.php/t-52649.html) for more.

There might be libraries that implement FTP (e.g. Curl), rsync etc. and provide a C++ interface.

Answer (score 0):

messing around with WinINet.dll can be quite painful.
QT has the class [`QFtp`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qftp.html) which does all the work for you.